# ERROR in The target entry-point "angular-formio" has missing dependencies: - @angular/elements

Tags: angular, compiler-errors, angular9, angular-forms, formio

> ERROR in The target entry-point "angular-formio" has missing
> dependencies:
>
> - @angular/elements

I am getting this error in the angular version

Angular CLI: 9.1.3

Node: 12.14.1

OS: win32 x64

Angular: 9.1.3

but after installing

```
npm i @angular/elements
```

the issue is not fixed if I install this, it is showing different error.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please add more context so people will be able to help, code snippets, errors, etc

Answer (score 1):

Do the following steps,

1. Take the backup of your existing app
2. Remove the node modules from the application
3. Clear the cache
4. npm install @angular/elements
5. npm install (will install all modules listed as dependencies in package.json)